# Can any one provide the code for merging two images in django

Tags: python, django

I tried merging two images in django. But I am unsuccessful can any one please provide me code for merging two imges such that , one image should be placed on another and to be saved as .jpg. My mail id is srikanthmadireddy78@gamil.com

Comment: I hope you are using a imaging library like pillow  ?  Also, keep your email private ??

Comment: What did you try? Post your unsuccessful code so that you can be helped.

Comment: Please show us what have you tried so far then only we can help , how can we help you out without knowing what have you tried which version you are using what problems you faced.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Python Imaging Library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow).

```
from PIL import Image

def merge_img(background, foreground):
    #Conver both images to same color mode
    if background.mode != 'RGBA':
        background = background.convert('RGBA')
    if foreground.mode != 'RGBA':
        foreground = foreground.convert('RGBA')

    layer = Image.new('RGBA', background.size, (0,0,0,0))

    #Scale images
    ratio = min(float(background.size[0]) / foreground.size[0], float(background.size[1]) / foreground.size[1])
    w = int(foreground.size[0] * ratio)
    h = int(foreground.size[1] * ratio)
    foreground = foreground.resize((w, h))

    #Paste foreground at the middle of background
    layer.paste(foreground, ((background.size[0] - w) // 2, (background.size[1] - h) // 2))
    return Image.composite(layer, background, layer)


background = Image.open('background.jpg')
foreground = Image.open('foreground.jpg')

img = merge_img(background, foreground)
img.save('merged.jpg')
```

Not necessarily to use `layer` and `Image.composite()`, you can get along only with `paste()`, but they will help to solve many problems. Especially if need to merge gif with jpeg.

Comment: If you add some information about PIL (what is it?, where can one find it?) and the code you might get some more upvotes.

Comment: @Matthias done. I hope it get better.